# Updating Column Based On Another Updated Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My question has to do with the order of updates in a single update statement. I have observed that when I set variables using a `SELECT` statement, that the variables are set in order. For example:

```
SELECT
    @Test1 = 2,
    @Test2 = @Test1 + 1
```

At this point `@Test1` will be `2` and `@Test2` will be `3` because the set operations are done in order. But what happens with `UPDATE`?

```
UPDATE TestTable SET
    Test1 = 2,
    Test2 = Test1 + 1
```

Will `Test2` use the initial value of `Test1` in its calculation or will it use the value we just set? Does it make any difference if it is an `UPDATE` statement inside of a `MERGE`?

```
MERGE INTO TestTable AS T
    USING (
        SELECT
                Test1,
                Test2
            FROM SomeOtherTable
        ) AS S
        ON S.Test1 = T.Test1
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            T.Test1 = 2,
            T.Test2 = T.Test1 + 1
    ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is specified the same in all SQL implementations - see this related issue in Teradata which allows early re-use of derived columns:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458700/early-or-re-ordered-re-use-of-derived-columns-in-a-query-is-this-valid-ansi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names on the right hand side of the assignment refer to the old values of the columns, regardless of the order they are in.

This (for example) allows you to swap two values without using a temporary variable.

```
UPDATE foo
SET a = b,
    b = a
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6984/1

---

The SQL-92 specification (Section 13.10, General Rules, Item 6 on page 395) states:

> - The `<value expression>`s are effectively evaluated for each row of T before updating any row of T.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere or just something that is known?

Comment: @Schmalls: "Is this documented somewhere?" Well, if it wasn't documented before, it is now. :) I *think* it's the behaviour required by the SQL standard, but I don't have a copy of it on hand that I can check.

Comment: I found it in the [SQL-92 specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). It is Section 13.10, General Rules, Item 6 on page 395.

Comment: @Schmalls: +1 Good find. I added a quote from your link in my answer.