# SQL update using values from the same record

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following statement, will `f1` always get the value that `f2` used to have? Or will `f2` sometimes get updated first and `f1` winds up with `NULL`? I am under the impression that the new values are not available within the statement, that `f2` has the old value while processing the record, but I can't find an authoritative place that says this.

```
UPDATE x
SET
    x.f1 = x.f2,
    x.f2 = NULL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Column Based On Another Updated Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402913/updating-column-based-on-another-updated-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conceptually the operation happens ["all at once"](http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=268800) so it will use the "before" values

Indeed

```
UPDATE x
SET
 x.f1 = x.f2,
 x.f2 = x.f1
```

would also work fine to swap the two column values.

Comment: Thanks! 'all at once' was the term/concept I needed to look up and read about. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

`f1` will always get `f2`'s previous value before the `UPDATE`.

Technically speaking the record is deleted, and reinserted. So SQL will work out what the new record should be, then delete the current record, and insert the new record afterwards.

This article regarding SQL Triggers may help explain:

> The deleted table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE and UPDATE statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to the deleted table. The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily have no rows in common.
>
> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: What do you mean "Technically speaking"  the record is deleted, and reinserted? SQL Server can do in place updates. And TBH I simply don't see the relevance of triggers here.

Comment: @MartinSmith See my quoted text. I was under the impression during an UPDATE records are deleted and inserted?

Comment: Only in some circumstances. e.g if the clustered index key column is updated and so the row needs to move.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah okay I was under the impression this happened every time, cheers for enlightening me. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith If this is the case, do rows only get deleted/reinserted when the index key is changed, and when a SQL Trigger is linked to the table?

Comment: A blog post looking at in place updates [is here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/06/21/are-all-updates-split-into-delete-insert/). I would need to test to be sure but AFAIK despite what BOL says in your quote an `UPDATE` on a table with a trigger won't actually be turned into a physical delete / insert on the table.

Comment: Thanks @Curt. I appreciate the detail and link.